# Script to change the compression of gziped files

Tags: compression, gzip

I was trying to change the compression of some gzip files from the default compression level (`6`) or any other compression level to the maximum compression level (`9`).

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to detect files with a default compression level, but the easiest way to set a new compression level is to simply uncompress then recompress:

```
for f in *.gz; do gunzip $f; gzip -9 ${f%.gz}; done
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution but does not detect the compression level:

```
for file in ${files_to_process[*]}
do
    (gunzip -c ${file} | gzip -9 > ${file}.moarcompression) && mv ${file}.moarcompression ${file}
done
```